# No Such Module ' ' error appears in XCTest immediately after creating Cocoa Touch Framework

Tags: swift, cocoa-touch, xctest, xcode9

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYs0y.png)

Why doesn't Cocoa Touch Framework work right out of the box? How can I resolve this. I tried adding $(srcroot) to the Framework Search Path and that didn't help at all.

Comment: try clean and rebuild

Comment: tried that several times.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add all main target dependencies to the test target!